# Django model's OneToOne relationship - AttributeError: object has no attribute

Tags: django, django-models, attributeerror

Please help !

I am building a simple maintenance ticketing system.

model **Ticket** captures the initial data.

model **UpdateTicket** enables a responder to update details on the **Ticket** as well as including additional field for comment and a timestamp.
**UpdatedTicket** has a OneToOne relationship with **Ticket** but I get an **AttributeError: 'Ticket' object has no attribute** when I try to access the associated data. I have entered some data into this table via the admin site and the relationships were working fine there.

Here are the models

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse
from members.models import Member

class Ticket(models.Model):
    """ model to represent maintenance issue ticket """
    # id = models
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='+', db_column='reporter')
    location = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, related_name='+', db_column='location')
    date_reported = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    contractor = models.ForeignKey('Contractor', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['date_reported']
        permissions = [
            ("can_message", "add a new message"),
            ("can_update", "update a ticket"),
        ]


    def __str__(self):
        """ string to return the model name as text"""
        return f'{self.reporter}, {self.date_reported} GOTO -> '

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Returns the url to access a particular ticket instance."""
        return reverse('maintenance-ticket', args=[str(self.id)])


class UpdatedTicket(models.Model):
    ticket = models.OneToOneField(Ticket, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='_ticket', primary_key=True,)
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=300, null=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['date_updated']

    def __str__(self):
        return f'referencing the OneToOneField'
```

this is what I have been trying with the errors (redacted)

```
>>> from maintenance.models import Ticket
>>> t = Ticket.objects.filter(id=9).first()

>>> t.updatedticket
AttributeError: 'Ticket' object has no attribute 'updatedticket'

>>> t.ticket
AttributeError: 'Ticket' object has no attribute 'ticket'

>>> t._ticket
KeyError: '_ticket'
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: maintenance_updatedticket.ticket_id

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: maintenance_updatedticket.ticket_id
```

and then, just to test the existence of data in the UpdatedTicket table;

```
>>> from maintenance.models import UpdatedTicket
>>> UpdatedTicket.objects.all()
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: maintenance_updatedticket.ticket_id
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: maintenance_updatedticket.ticket_id
```

I thought referencing fields in tables with OneToOne relationships was going to be a simple thing. Help would be enormously appreciated with understanding where I am going wrong.

here are the migrations

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion
import django.utils.timezone


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Ticket',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('date_reported', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)),
                ('description', models.TextField(max_length=100))
                ('contractor', models.ForeignKey(null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.PROTECT, to='maintenance.contractor')),
                ('location', models.ForeignKey(db_column='location', null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.PROTECT, related_name='+', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
                ('reporter', models.ForeignKey(db_column='reporter', null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='+', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
            options={
                'ordering': ['date_reported'],
                'permissions': [('can_eat_scones', 'eat scones'), ('can_message', 'add a new message'), ('can_update', 'update a ticket')],
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='UpdatedTicket',
            fields=[
                ('ticket', models.OneToOneField(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name='_ticket', serialize=False, to='maintenance.ticket')),
                ('comment', models.TextField(max_length=300, null=True)),
                ('date_updated', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)),
            ],
            options={
                'ordering': ['date_updated'],
            },
        ),
    ]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you created and applied your migrations?

Comment: yes, see updated post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think was been caused by a mismatch in the model id's created throughout the development of the two tables. it's kind of been fixed by deleting all of the migrations and the related tables from the sqlite database from the dbshell and starting again.